# Thymeleaf hasAuthority() not correct after logout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm having a bit of a fight with Theymleaf's security implementation.

I have the following spring security configuration:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN"))
          .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
        .formLogin()
          // ...
          .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
          .invalidateHttpSession(true);
  }
```

In my HTML I've got something simple set up:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">You're cool bro!</div>
```

Which, after logging in works perfectly fine.
Logging out also works perfectly fine and hides the div.

However when I login after which I re-start the server (and thus my session is destroyed) and just reload the page(homepage, base url, without logging in) the div is back and thymeleaf seems to 'cache' the authorities.

Another effect is that I'm still able to visit pages like: `/admin/page/`

Am I missing something magically here? I'm confused as to what the Thymeleaf `hasAuthority()` method calls.

I'm thinking about just adding the following, which I feel is rather unclean:

```java
@PreDestroy
private void destroySecurityContext() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
  }
```

Comment: What is the page URL you are trying to browse? Also what kind of restart is it? Is it a reload of the application (which is managed by Spring boot devtools?

Comment: Slightly edited the question; I just reload the base url (homepage, '/').
It happens when I fully stop and start the server; reloading with devtools behaves as expected

Comment: Looks like this is not specific to Thymeleaf. Are you using some shared session where the authenticated information is kept.

Comment: Nope, just the basic spring security

Comment: Open your inspector and see if the request has been cached. Also this is 100% unrelated to thymeleaf, even if it is not a caching problem, it'd be spring security, not thymeleaf. Thymeleaf is only showing you the issue, it can't be the issue.